# Playing sound automatically in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, audio

Hi everyone I am trying to play a sound in swift on my xcode game on launch automatically and I have tried a bunch of different code. I was able to write and run the it in Objective - C like below in the viewdidload method, I created a method for the sound itself and called that in viewdidload.

```
-(void)Loadingsound {

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(Loadingsound);

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *LoadingSound = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tap Sound" ofType:@"wav"]];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)LoadingSound, &Loadingsound);

[self Loadingsound];
```

But now I am trying to replicate the same in swift but I am not able to do so. I saw this code below in another question asked on stack overflow but since now this is on Xcode 7.2.1 and Swift 2.0, is it possible that there is a new way to write this? This is the code I that I tried and the sound does not load when the game starts.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()


if let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Tap Sound", withExtension: "wav") {
        var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0

        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)

        // Play

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
}
```

Also another way I tried of running the code was...

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()

var loadingsound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: 

NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Tap Sound", ofType: "wav"))

    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: loadingsound, error: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

        audioPlayer.play()
```

In this method when I try running it, the complies fails and shows an error which tells me to put an "!" sign after tying in "wav" and putting the bracket after that. After I put in the exclamation sign it tells me to replace the word "error" below and putin "filetypeHint" instead. Someone please help me out with this. The original was working sooo well in objective-c, can someone please help me in translating that exact code to swift. The other examples I saw as I showed were showing errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check If your "Tap Sound" soundfile is in your project target. You need to load via `URLForResource` and like in my case don't set the extension type. You only need the filename. You can put it in a method like this.

```
func playMusic(_ filename: String) {
    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    if (url == nil) {
       print("Could not find file: \(filename)")
       return
    }

    do {
        try audioPlayer =  AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)
        let player = audioPlayer

        // From Documentation: Negative integer value to loop the sound indefinitely until you call the stop method.
        player!.numberOfLoops = -1
        player!.prepareToPlay()
        player!.play()
    } catch _ {
        audioPlayer = nil;
    } 
}

// call the function with your soundfile
playMusic("Tap Sound")
```

Comment: Thanks alot man! I tried out ur code and I ran the method in the viewdidload like the way you said by using playMusic("Tap Sound") and it worked when the app launched!! Before it wasn't able to find the file in the target and now it is. Thanks alot for ur help bro!

Comment: Yeah, nice that it works and that I could helped you.

Comment: @GianmarcoBelmonte when upgrading from very old Swift, please don't forget the `_` in the method signatures.